# problems in fetching upgrades

Tags: upgrade

presently using ubuntu 10.04 and I would like to upgrade to the latest ubuntu release but while trying to ugrade I have this errors . Can anybody help me how to solve this and proceed..just a beginner in using ubuntu. thanks

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta/linux-image-generic_2.6.32.38.44_i386.deb
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta/linux-headers-generic_2.6.32.38.44_i386.deb
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]

Comment: what is the output when you type the following into a terminal?  `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` ?  copy and paste the output you see into pastebin.com please.

Answer (score 2):

Fossfreedom has it right.  2.6.32.38 was superceded by [linux-image-generic_2.6.32.40.47_i386.deb](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta/linux-image-generic_2.6.32.40.47_i386.deb).  You need to get your apt local databases in sync before you upgrade.

This is accomplished by successfully completing a `sudo apt-get update`