# Cannot download anything on ubuntu, any ideas?

Tags: downloads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [problems in fetching upgrades](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117761/problems-in-fetching-upgrades)

It says that it can not connect to the internet and it shows me the following, when I'm actually on-line at the moment and chating away:

Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg_17.0.963.79~r125985-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 00.000.00.000 00]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-browser_17.0.963.79~r125985-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 00.000.00.000 00]

(next to IP: there is my actual IP address)
And it is not just for downloading chronium, it is anything I try to download.

Comment: Also this one: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-browser-l10n_17.0.963.79~r125985-0ubuntu1_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 00.000.00.000 00]

Comment: There is no such file exist. From where you got this link?

Comment: what happens when you open a terminal and `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Can you clarify your question ,
cant download packages or cant download any files?

Answer (score -1):

The reason for the error you get is because of server side issues. To resolve these issues, you can try switching your current server to the main server.

To switch your server, open '**Software Sources**' and click on the drop down list for '**Download from**:'. You can then choose 'Main server'.

or you may try [Package Manager Troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure)

Comment: No.  The issue is that the file doesn't exist because of stale apt-get database...same as the other question